# How many attachments can be made under one handle in sqlite for iOS/in general?

Tags: ios, sqlite

So I have essentially have 4 databases (files), under one handle. 2 of those database files are sync databases. So I am attaching/detaching all the time. My thought is that I can maintain all databases under one class using a "DRY" approach. After reading online, I have noticed some talk that sqlite has a max database attachments of 3? Could someone please clarify this? I am getting noticeably edgy results when I say, run a query, using an attach command with an alias name. Hopefully I am clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_attached) says:

> The number of simultaneously attached databases is limited to SQLITE_MAX_ATTACHED which is set to 10 by default.